# How to apply a WPF style to all elements of a particular type?

Tags: wpf, styles

```
<Window.Resources>   
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">    
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Times New Roman" />   
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />    
   <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />     
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFCA5132" /> 
 </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This aboved code looks like the right selection to apply WPF style to all buttons in a specific window. But I want to apply this style for all buttons in my program. 
I think I need to write down this code in the `<Application.Resources></Application.Resources>`. But it doesn't run. How can I do that?

Comment: What happens when you write this in Application.Resources. Do you get a compiler error? If so, can you tell us what the error is.

Comment: There, formatted your code. For future reference, put four spaces before each line or code, and, for code inline `like this` surround it with backticks (``asdasd``). Now, to the question, what happens when you put this in the Application.Resources?

Answer (score 1):

`<Application.Resources>` is a `ResourceDictionary`. You can't add to it both a `ResourceDictionary` and a `Style`, like you are doing in your code. Place the `Style` inside the `ResourceDictionary`, like this:

```
<Application.Resources>     

 <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero
                        , Version=3.0.0.0,Culture=neutral
                        , PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
                        , ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml">            
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     <ResourceDictionary Source="Style\AppStyle.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="meiryo" />
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    </Style>   
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But It still cannot run.
BTW, I have another solutions. 
In AppStyle.xaml file, I create a style for window form and place my button style at there. It runs properly!